# DataTables Hide Data Network Tab

Tags: php, jquery, codeigniter, datatables, codeigniter-3

New to using [datatables](https://datatables.net/) and PHP / Codeigniter. I'm selecting all data from a MySQL database and displaying this in a very simple datatable. ALl works well so far, filtering as expected.

I'm able to see the returned JSON data when I view my browsers network tab, this is great for testing, but what about when my table contains sensitive data (list of names & addresses) - is there any way I can hide this response? I don't want visitors to my site to be able to click the network tab and view **any** data.

Do I need to look at server side processing or an alternative?

I've been [reading](https://datatables.net/examples/server_side/post.html) about using `POST` instead of `GET`, but i'm not even sure how to implement that. Whenevr I change my AJAX type to `POST` - I can still see the returned results in the network tab.

My code so far;

**JS**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#books').DataTable({
        "ajax": {
            url : "<?php echo base_url("books") ?>",
            type : 'GET'
        },
    });
});
</script>
```

**HTML**

```
<table id="books">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>ID</th>
            <th>Title</th>
            <th>Author</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
</table>
```

**PHP**

```
public function books() {
    // Datatables Variables
    $draw = intval($this->input->get("draw"));
    $start = intval($this->input->get("start"));
    $length = intval($this->input->get("length"));

    $books= $this->Admin_model->getAllBooks();

    foreach($books->result() as $r) {

           $data[] = array(
                $r->id,
                $r->title,
                $r->author,
           );
    }

    $output = array(
        "draw" => $draw,
        "recordsTotal" => $books->num_rows(),
        "recordsFiltered" => $books->num_rows(),
        "data" => $data
    );

    echo json_encode($output);
    exit();
}
```

Comment: `is there any way I can hide this response? I don't want visitors to my site to be able to click the network tab and view any data.` No that's not possible. For the data to be shown on the site it has to be publicly accessible. It sounds more like you need a method of authentication, assuming you don't already have one.

Comment: Thanks @Rory McCrossan you're probably right. I may consider a login area or similar. I thought it was possible to filter the results at the server side and not display them to the end user :/

Comment: for authentication with CI: https://github.com/benedmunds/CodeIgniter-Ion-Auth